# Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

### I'm getting issue when i'm hitting URL

#### My Controller

> > Please help me out find my error from my title

```
  @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/client")
    public class TestController {
    
        @PostMapping(produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
    
    public ResponseEntity<Client> createCustomer(@RequestBody Client customer) {
            
            System.out.println("Creat Customer: " + customer);
            
            return ResponseEntity.ok(customer);
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: `ok` - *A shortcut for creating a ResponseEntity with the given body and the status set to OK.* - why do you think that the `customer` object would be a good body?

Comment: Make sure you are able to serialize and deserialize an object of type `Client` (i.e. jackson is properly configured).

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you have a "normal" spring web mvc.

```
@RequestMapping(value="client", produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
public @ResponseBody Customer createCustomer(
    @RequestParam Customer customer) {

        ...do some work like customerDao.create(customer);

        System.out.println("Create Customer: " + customer);

        return customer;
}
```

If this is a REST-Interface then you need to first deserialize your incoming data. If your data is xml you can do it e.g. with a JAXB2-Marshaller. If you have JSON-data you can use FasterXML(Jackson) in the same way. Your code could look like

```
@RequestMapping(value="client", produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
public @ResponseBody Customer createCustomer(
    @RequestBody String body) {

        Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(body));
        RestRequest restRequest = (RestRequest)jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(source);

        Customer customer = (Customer) restRequest.getRequestData();

        ...do some work like customerDao.create(customer);

        System.out.println("Create Customer: " + customer);

        return customer;
}
```